# Can I create a tree of combo boxes

Tags: install4j

I am developing a custom screen for my installer and would like to have tree of combo boxes similar to that presented in the install components predefined screen

Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 0):

As of install4j 5.1.x, no such form component is available.